# Android java unit testing for checking availability of code

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, cookies, webview

I have added an activity in a app. In which I have one variable and I just want to test if it variable exist then ok or if it doesn't then fail the test. And if specific line of code is removed or commented then also fail the test. Let me explain in detail.

First of all I have web view in my activity and I am passing user agent in webview. webview will not open correctly without user-agent value. So I want a test case that if in future anyone removed that line which is setting user-agent then test case should fail.

Similarly there was is a line in code:
    @inject LoginResult login;
on top of code and it contains login details which I am sending in cookies to make user already logged in (Single Sign On) and I want the test case to fail in this case too that if someone remove that variable or more like fail it if someone remove the line which is setting cookies in webview.

I have check SO and couldn't find that is there any way I can check these things.

Answer (score 1):

For sure the tests will fail (to compile) if you remove from code variables referenced in tests.

Comment: how can I reference any variable in test? It will be great help for me to proceed with this.

Comment: secondly if someone not just removed the variable but just change its string to emtpy string then how can I fail that test?

Comment: testing is new for me and if you just only tell me how can I reference or a nice tutorial about this then it will be a great help for me.

Comment: Show some code, what you have tried and people would help you from there. This is a great starting point: https://developer.android.com/studio/test/index.html to introduce testing to your project.